# How to use rgb color in scss?

Tags: html, css, codeigniter, sass

I'm using sccs. But when I use rgb/rgba color, then showing error. Otherwise It's work very well.

**Error message:**

[image]

If I use this, It's working.

```
$color: #f5325c;

.class-name {
    background-color: $color; 
 }
```

But If I use this, showing error:

```
$color:rgba(15,34,58,.12);

.class-name {
    background-color: $color;
}
```

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, It works for me well, check the element (class) you are applying to. check my codepen here https://codepen.io/jv18creator/pen/JjKmozN?editors=1100

Comment: @JeetViramgama I checked your codepen example. It's working good. But what's wrong with me! :(

Comment: what editor and browser you are using?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 11.1 and Google Chrome.

Comment: sorry mate, I don't understand what's going on but it's supporting hex values you should try this site https://www.hexcolortool.com/#f5325d it can help a little bit.

Comment: This is a third party library, this is not an issue with codeigniter.

Comment: Which sass version are you using? Try to upgrade if there is a newer version.

Comment: OK. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that there is an issue with your scssphp compiler. It is not supporting the rgba value. Please see the thread.
https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/5058

Comment: There is also a link on the github issue page saying it should be fixed (https://github.com/scssphp/scssphp/commit/033accd47af0210c8db078f5be5a29fe43973ce2). I guess OP just needs to upgrade the sass version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a problem here in your scss code. 
you can even use css [variables](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_var_old) if you want.

Comment: But it's not the problems solution. Thanks :)

Comment: sorry man cause i run your code.... It's showing the right output... It's silly but can you try to make alpha value to .6 or .7 ? rgba(15,34,58,.7);